# Find steps in path (depth) for a node using neo4j and/or python

Tags: python, graph, neo4j, cypher, shortest-path

I have the following graph

[image: graph]

Each of those relationships are "`USES_COMPONENT`"

After normalizing the neo4j cypher results, I have a structure like

```
{
    '1': {
        'label': 'Product', 
        'properties': {...}, 
        'type': 'VERTEX'
    },
    '2': {
        'label': 'Component', 
        'properties': {...}, 
        'type': 'VERTEX'
    }, 
    '3': {
        'label': 'USES_COMPONENT', 
        'properties': {...}, 
        'type': 'EDGE', 
        'direction': 'OUT', 
        'from': '1', 
        'to': '2'
    }
}
```

Which ultimately describes the entire graph (very similar to the raw cypher response)

My current cypher query is: (The uuid of Froot Loops is `a1`. I assigned this.)

```
MATCH p = (pr:Product)-[:USES_COMPONENT*]->()
WHERE pr.meta_uuid = 'a1'
RETURN p
```

**What I need to do is find how many steps away from the root (Froot Loops) each component is**.

So `Corn Flour Blend` would be `1` step away, while `Whole Grain Yellow Corn Flour` would be `2` steps away.

I am happy with either a cypher implementation or a python implementation. Or, a combination of the two.

Some notes:

1. I am in full control of the graph data, and the way it is normalized (above). I'd like to keep it as close to this as possible, but I *can* tweak it
2. Performance is important, but none of these graphs will be rediculously large. I would be surprised if (total) any product had more than 200 components (at any depth)
3. I am happy to include third-party libraries, if anyone knows of one
4. I am only worried about the `USES_COMPONENT` relationship, and that will never be circular. No matter how far *out* you follow a `USES_COMPONENT` path, it will never hit Froot Loops.

I appreciate everyone's help. I am not even entirely sure what to google, so if I've missed something obvious, a link would be appreciated.

Comment: You need the entire path or the nodes with the distance from the root is sufficient?

Comment: nodes with distance should be fine. I just need to figure out that "Whole Grain Yellow Corn Flour" is 2 steps away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the nodes with the distance from the root is sufficient as you said in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45450560/find-steps-in-path-depth-for-a-node-using-neo4j-and-or-python/45450770#comment77862541_45450560), this query should work:

```
MATCH p = (pr:Product)-[r:USES_COMPONENT*]->(n)
WHERE pr.meta_uuid = 'a1'
RETURN n, size(r)
```

This query uses the [size()](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/scalar/#functions-size) function to get the number of `r` relationships between `pr` (the root) and each `n` node.

Comment: That is perfect. For anyone who wants to know, you can also `RETURN n, size(r), p` if you want the path as well. The path wasn't important for my case, but I played around with it.